# Spark throws Error: FileNotFoundException when writing data frame to S3

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, amazon-s3

1. we have a data frame which we want to write to s3 as parquet format and in overwrite mode.
2. every time we write the dataframe it's always a new folder. The code to write the S3 location is as follows:

```
        df.write
          .option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
          .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
          .option("maxRecordsPerFile", maxRecordsPerFile)
          .mode("overwrite")
          .format(format)
          .save(output)
```

What we observe is, at times we get `FilenotFoundException` (full trace below). I would like to understand:

1. when I am writing to a new S3 location (meaning nobody is reading from the location); why does the writing program throw the below exception?
2. how to fix it? I see couple of Stack Overflow questions pointing to this exception. But they say that it happens when you try to read when write is happening. But my case is not like that. I don't read when write happens.
3. my spark is `2.3.2` ; `EMR-5.18.1` ; the code is written in `scala`
4. I am using `s3://` as output folder path. Should I change it to some `s3n` or `s3a` ? will that help?

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory 's3://BUCKET/snapshots/FOLDER/_bid_9223370368440344985/part-00020-693dfbcb-74e9-45b0-b892-0b19fa92365c-c000.snappy.parquet'
It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:109)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:461)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$4.apply(HashAggregateExec.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$4.apply(HashAggregateExec.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$26.apply(RDD.scala:853)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$26.apply(RDD.scala:853)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: Problem seems to be with the source. Whats the source of df and how frequently it gets updated?

Check this: https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D53f00001Pm5fsCAB/error-writing-parquet-files

Comment: the source are immutable json files. New json files keep adding to the sources. in any case they dont get updated/ deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to solve the problem

1. The `df : DataFrame` was formed on the same `s3` folder to which the same is being written in `overwrite` mode.
2. So during the `overwrite`; the source folder is getting cleared --which was resulting into the error

Hope this helps somebody.